# How is this Functor instance implemented?

Tags: haskell, functor

```
data GenTree f a -- kind (* -> *) -> * -> *
    = Node (f (GenTree f a))
    | Leaf a

instance Functor f => Functor (GenTree f) where
    fmap f (Node ts) = Node (fmap (fmap f) ts)
    fmap f (Leaf x)  = Leaf (f x)
```

I don't understand the `fmap (fmap f) ts` statement in the above Functor instance. Can somebody explain why it's written this way?

Comment: It might be enlightening to try to figure out how you think it should look instead.

Comment: Using `f` both as a type variable and as an argument of `fmap` might confuse you. I'd avoid that.

Comment: Hm. This is free monad. https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-11.0/free-5.0.1/Control-Monad-Free.html#t:Free

Comment: `fmap` turns `f :: a->b` into `fmap f :: F a -> F b` where `F` is a functor. By the same reasoning, we get `fmap (fmap f) :: G (F a) -> G (F b)` where both are functors. In your case, `F = GenTree f` and `G = f`, so that `G(F a) = f (GenTree f a)` which is the type of `ts`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the structure of `Node` it contains an `f (GenTree f a)`, so if we look at the types of the expression in question:

```
fmap f (Node ts) = Node (fmap (fmap f) ts)
```

`f` here is of type `a -> b`

`ts` is of type `f (GenTree f a)`, but we should be aware that the `f` in this expression is not the function above, but actually the type constructor. In order to get rid of confusion we'll rename the function above to `g` as follows:

```
fmap g (Node ts) = Node (fmap (fmap g) ts)
```

Now in order to apply our function `g`, we'll need to get a hold of an actual value of `a`. We know that our `f` type constructor has a `Functor` instance, so if we map over it we get a `GenTree f a`:

```
fmap (\tree -> ...) ts
```

Now that we have our `GenTree` we can recursively call `fmap` on it so that at some point we'll get to the Leaves and actually apply our function to the value, if we wrote this out in all of its boilerplate, it'd look like this:

```
fmap g (Node ts) = Node (fmap (\tree -> fmap g tree) ts)
```

So in essence it is written that way, because we need to `fmap` over both the `f` type constructor and the actual `GenTree`.

Comment: Reasoning about the type of `(fmap g)` helped me understand this. Thanks!